# safari gray html color

Tags: html, colors, safari

Can someone please tell me what the html color of the safari browser is?

I had found it at one point, but have since forgotten and lost the source.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari's window frame is a gradient.  You can use the eyedropper tool of any modern picture editor to find the colors.  The top navigation bar appears to be from grays as light as `#C5C5C5` to grays as dark as `#969696`, excluding borders.

[image: Safari]

Comment: +1, just an add, for complete response, you can use lot of modern picture editor ( [new Gimp (open source)](http://www.gimp.org/), photoShop...) for select color in your desktop (color in other windows program), and you can use browser's plugin than [Colorzilla](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/colorzilla/) for select all color in the webpage visited...